# How would I extract the user agent strings from a log file?

Tags: logs, awk

Currently I am running a command like this, to get the most requested content:

```
grep "17\/Jul\/2011" other_vhosts_access.log | awk '{print $8}' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

I want to now see the user agent strings, but the problem is they include several spaces. Here is a typical log file line. The UA is the last section delimited by quotation marks:

```
example.com:80 [ip] - - [17/Jul/2011:23:59:59 +0100] "GET [url] HTTP/1.1" 200 6449 "[referer]" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/12.0.742.122 Safari/534.30"
```

Is there a better tool than awk for this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If that format is consistent and the field is really wrapped in double quotes you can use either awk or cut with `"` as the field delimiter:

```
awk -F\" '{print $6}'
```

or:

```
cut -d\" -f 6
```

Answer (score 3):

```
perl -ne 'if(/"([^"]+)"$/){$ua{$1}++;} END{for(keys %ua){print "$ua{$_} $_\n"}}' \
  access_log
```